# How emulate &sname call from XS?

Tags: perl, perl-xs, perlapi

How to emulate `z` sub behavior within `XS` sub?

```
package XS;
sub hello {
    print "ARGS: >>@_<<\n";
    my $lvl;
    while( my @frame =  caller( $lvl++ ) ) {
        print ">>@frame[0..4]<<\n";
    }
}

sub z {
    &hello;
}
```

In my `.xs` file I have:

```
void
call_perl() {
    call_pv( "XS::hello", G_NOARGS );    
}

void
test(...)
    CODE:
        call_perl();
```

But calling `XS::test(1,2,3)` do not pass any arguments to `hello`.

The output:

```
ARGS: >><<
>>main -e 1 XS::hello <<
```

Here we can see that `$hasargs` flag is not set because of `G_NOARG` flag, but why `@_` is flushed? What did I miss?

**UPD**
Seems found an half of the answer.

1. [G_NOARGS](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html#G_NOARGS) flag

   > has the effect of not creating the @_ array for the Perl subroutine.
2. When `XSUB` is called the perl do not create the frame for it (can not remember where this is described) and do not fill `@_` for it (this described **indirectly** [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html#The-Argument-Stack))

   > XSUBs refer to their stack arguments with the macro ST(x)

So the more precise question will be:

**How to propagate `XSUB` stack arguments to `PP` subroutine?**

NOTICE: I can not just use:

```
call_pv( "XS::hello", 0 );
```

Because this is ordinal PP sub call. And when it returns the `XSUB` stack arguments will be replaced by a return value from `XS::hello` sub

```
int count =  call_pv( "XS::hello", 0 );
STAGAIN;
printf( "%s\n", SvPV_nolen( ST(0) ) );
```

So I supply `G_NOARGS` flag to be able to access `XSUB` stack arguments after call to `PP` sub

Comment: Could you post the generated .c on pastebin or something?

Comment: @ikegami: sources and generated `.c` [here](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/566429)

Comment: Can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for `XSUB` how it is done (NOTICE: I do not handle return arguments in this example):

```
test(...)
CODE:
    AV *defav_old =  GvAV(PL_defgv);   # Save current @_

    AV *av = newAV();                  # Create new array
    av_extend(av, items -1);          
    AvREIFY_only(av);
    AvFILLp(av) =  items -1;
    Copy(MARK+1, AvARRAY(av), items, SV*); # Fill array by elements from stack

    GvAV(PL_defgv) =  av;     # point @_ to our new array


    PUSHMARK(SP);
    int count =  call_pv( "XS::Utils::hello", G_VOID | G_NOARGS );

    GvAV(PL_defgv) =  defav_old;  # Restore old @_
```